# Firebase: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':android:natives' after it has been resolved

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, libgdx

I'm following the "Save and retrieve" guide in Android Studio for setting up firebase database.

Note! The sync is running without a error when I'm not following the guide.

The problem is on step 2. When I click "Add the Realtime database to your app" it works fine and the system puts

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Like this:

```
android {
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
compileSdkVersion 27
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "se.filipfahlstrom.quiz"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
task copyAndroidNatives() {
file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
    def outputDir = null
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
    if (outputDir != null) {
        copy {
            from zipTree(jar)
            into outputDir
            include "*.so"
        }
    }
}
}
 task run(type: Exec) {
def path
def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
if (localProperties.exists()) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
        properties.load(instr)
    }
    def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
    if (sdkDir) {
        path = sdkDir
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }
} else {
    path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
}

def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher'
}

eclipse {
// need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
// ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
    }
}

jdt {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}

classpath {
    plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
    containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
}

project {
    name = appName + "-android"
    natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
    buildCommands.clear();
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
    buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
}
}

idea {
module {
    sourceDirs += file("src");
    scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

    iml {
        withXml {
            def node = it.asNode()
            def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
            builder.current = node;
            builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                    configuration {
                        option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then I get a message saying "Dependencies set up correctly" and step 2 is done. However, when I try to sync the project i get an error message:

```
Cannot change strategy of configuration ':android:natives' after it has been resolved.
```

and

```
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':android:natives' after it has been resolved.     at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$_failOnVersionConflictForGroup_closure12.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:297)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:154)
at org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection$all.call(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.failOnVersionConflictForGroup(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:296)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$failOnVersionConflictForGroup.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.apply(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:107)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.apply(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:164)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$200(DefaultPluginManager.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:252)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:125)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:120)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:143)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at build_4f0t9dxrn3kib4apxwtxs6j8w.run(C:\Users\zfilfah\Downloads\quiz\android\build.gradle:137)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:204)
at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:209)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:136)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:261)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I delete

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and sync the project I'm back to step 1 again, and the sync works again.

How can I sync step 2 without an error?

Comment: Have you also tried to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'` to your dependencies section as well?

Comment: Yes like this:     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'

Comment: I didn't see this dependencies in your code. And it works?

Comment: Yes, I added that at the bottom in the dependencies folder but the error hasn't changed.